# Null being passed to Spring Security UserDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to add login to my webapp using spring security.

This is the first time I am trying to add spring-security 3.2 using pure code config (I have used it several times before with the xml config and the standard `UserDetailsService` implementation).

I have also seen other similar questions around moving to 3.2 but all relate to csrf stuff - which I have currently disabled just to rule those changes out.

My config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/dashboard").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/sign-up").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/loginprocess")
                .failureUrl("/?loginFailure=true")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll();
    }

     @Override
     protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
     }

     @Bean 
     public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder(){
         return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
     }
```

My login form looks like this:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="loginprocess" method="POST">
    <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Already Registered?</h3>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name='j_username' placeholder="User name">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name='j_password' placeholder="Password"><br/>
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value='Sign in' >
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#" >Sign up</a>
</form>
```

Finally, I try to log in and whilst debugging and working through the code, in my implementation of the UserDetailsService:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
    username = username.toLowerCase();
```

I see that the username string being passed in here is always null - being as this is all being invoked by the underlying spring mechanism I am struggling to see what is happening to the values in my submitted login form.

I have looked earlier on and walked through the spring code including the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` class and it seems that the obtainUsername(request) call is just getting null from the request.

Can anyone advise what might be wrong or where a good place to start looking would be? where does the username/password get set in the request object by spring?

---

**UPDATE**

I have also tried changing just the action url of the form and posting to a normal MVC controller - debugging that, the posted data is present and correct in the parameterMap - so it seems like it is something in the security chain that is removing my posted data from the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation suggests that the username / password fields must have specific names :-

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#jc

> The username must be present as the HTTP parameter named username
>
> The password must be present as the HTTP parameter named password

Try that and see if it works ?

Comment: ... im swearing a lot right now. Why would they do that to me? Even walking through the code in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java defaults to j_username.  So good work Mikey.

Comment: seriously.. why would you have different default names depending on whether you use xml/code configuration?

Comment: Java config has some differences and I am not sure why they didn't keep the same default values for parameter names. See http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security. We have to use ...formLogin().passwordParameter("j_password").usernameParameter("j_username")... to keep old names.